# How to fix Malformed help URL while opening ACC ATG?

Tags: jboss, atg, atg-dynamo

I'm using `jboss + mysql` for running ATG. I'm trying to open Admin Control Center through dyn/admin. However, I'm getting malformed help URL before I get login form. Once I logged in, I'm getting multiple alerts of same exception but with different help ids.

[image: Exception while opening ACC]

Did any one face this issue and found a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been observed because of not having protocol.jar in classpath while starting jboss server. You can follow this workaround to fix the issue.

Copy `%DYNAMO_HOME%/DAS/lib/protocol.jar` to `C:\lib` or any folder that is easily accessible to you.

Open `Standalone.conf.bat`
and add following line in the file.

`set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\lib"`

Open the Jboss server after the above update is done. The error will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic:
Copy the protocol.jar form DAS\lib to your domain lib folder and restart weblogic.
Ex: C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\lib